# Ruby gem to generate regex examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

A while back I came across a ruby gem that, given a regular expression, would generate example strings.

For example, given the regex:

```
/[a-z]{5}[0-9]{4}/
```

it could generate the string:

```
"hkdbv4578"
```

Anybody remember the name of this gem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for: https://github.com/benburkert/randexp  Randexp

Comment: If you're looking for a more "complete" gem, that actually handles the full regexp language (including character sets, for example which randexp does not!), check out: https://github.com/tom-lord/regexp-examples

Comment: Also, if you just want to "generate a dummy email address" or similar, you'd probably prefer to use something like: https://github.com/stympy/faker

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look around, couldnt find a gem, but found this https://github.com/repeatedly/ruby-string-random.

Looks like you can generate a string from a regular expression using it.

As a side note, I've found [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) to be invaluable when testing regex's in ruby.

Answer (score -1):

All of the available regex gems can be found at RubyGems [here](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=regex).

Perhaps an easier way for you to test Ruby Regular Expressions would be to use [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/).

Comment: I am aware of the RubyGems site and have attempted to find this gem before I posted the question.

Rubular is an excellent site, but exactly the opposite of what I need for 2 reasons: 1) it's a webapp, not a gem, 2) I'm not trying to test regular expressions, but rather generate example strings from regular expressions automatically.